# Make an iterator from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, iterator

I am currently modifying some code and **trying to not mess with the initial <s>structure</s> code**. Having a `for...of` loop over an array, and having a second array with an identical structure, I am wondering if there is a quick way to make a generator over my second array to simulate a zip.

Here's an example:

```js
const firstArray = ["a", "b", "c"];
const myAdditionalArray = [1, 2, 3];
// const generatorOverMyAdditionalAray = ???
for (const item of firstArray) {
  // Initial code doing stuff with item
  const additionalItem = myAdditionalArray.next();  
  // More code doing stuff with item and additionalItem
}
```

For pythonistas, it would look something like that

```py
>>> a = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> b = [1, 2, 3]
>>> generator_over_b = (x for x in b)
>>> for item in a:
...     additional_item = next(generator_over_b)
...     print(item, additional_item)
... 
a 1
b 2
c 3
```

Edit: Added emphasis on why `for` or `forEach` loops are not a viable solution (and ultimately do not answer the question)

Comment: Use a normal `for` loop or `forEach` loop and use the index to get the corresponding value from the other array.

Comment: @adiga why not use an iterator?

Comment: @VLAZ accessing using index is simple and readable. If I see an iterator, it won't be apparent immediately and I'd have to double to check to see if there is a reason for using iterator.

Comment: @adiga XY solution, though. You're solving the the "What I prefer" as the Y.

Comment: @adiga as said in the question, I'm trying to not mess with the initial structure right now. So, no `for`, no `forEach` and no zipping either.

Comment: @VLAZ their expected output was a 1, b 2 etc. The duplicate answers that. They haven't mentioned why `for` can't be used here over `for..of`

Comment: @adiga But they *have* mentioned they want an iterator. And the duplicate does not have any such answer. Here is a litmus test - if I type in "how to use iterator from array" in a search engine, and land on this question does the duplicate answer my query? No, it doesn't. XY

Comment: @VLAZ also, if they are iterating over a `Set` or a `Map`, they can't get items based on an index. So, there might be use case for this. Reopening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays have a `values` method for getting an iterator:

```js
const firstArray = ["a", "b", "c"];
const generatorOverMyAdditionalAray = [1, 2, 3].values();
for (const item of firstArray) {
  const additionalItem = generatorOverMyAdditionalAray.next().value;  
  console.log(item, additionalItem);
}
```

You could also implement a `zip` like generator, using `[Symbol.iterator]` -- which is the method an object should have when it is [iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#iterables):

```js
function* zip(...args) {
    const iters = args.map(arg => arg[Symbol.iterator]());
    while (true) {
        const results = iters.map(iter => iter.next());
        if (results.some(({done}) => done)) break;
        yield results.map(({value}) => value);
    }
}

const arg1 = "abc";
const arg2 = [1, 2, 3];
const arg3 = new Set(["X", "Y", "Z"]);
for ([a, b, c] of zip(arg1, arg2, arg3)) {
    console.log(a, b, c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Array#values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values) gives an iterator over an array:

```js
const firstArray = ["a", "b", "c"];
const myAdditionalArray = [1, 2, 3];

const generatorOverMyAdditionalAray = myAdditionalArray.values();

for (const item of firstArray) {
  // Initial code doing stuff with item
  const additionalItem = generatorOverMyAdditionalAray.next();  
  // More code doing stuff with item and additionalItem
  console.log(item, additionalItem.value);
}
```

In general, `for..of` uses the [iteration protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) so using it on a value will fetch an iterator using the well-known [`@@iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator). For arrays, the symbol is aliased to `.value`, so the two are equivalent:

```js
const firstArray = ["a", "b", "c"];
const myAdditionalArray = [1, 2, 3];

const generatorOverMyAdditionalAray = myAdditionalArray[Symbol.iterator]();

for (const item of firstArray) {
  // Initial code doing stuff with item
  const additionalItem = generatorOverMyAdditionalAray.next();  
  // More code doing stuff with item and additionalItem
  console.log(item, additionalItem.value);
}
```

The `@@iterator` symbol can be used with any iterable, for example, a set:

```js
const firstArray = ["a", "b", "c"];
const myAdditionalSet = new Set()
  .add(1)
  .add(2)
  .add(1) //duplicate will be removed 
  .add(3);

const generatorOverMyAdditionalAray = myAdditionalSet[Symbol.iterator]();

for (const item of firstArray) {
  // Initial code doing stuff with item
  const additionalItem = generatorOverMyAdditionalAray.next();  
  // More code doing stuff with item and additionalItem
  console.log(item, additionalItem.value);
}
```

Or a string:

```js
const firstArray = ["a", "b", "c"];
const myAdditionalString = "123";

const generatorOverMyAdditionalAray = myAdditionalString[Symbol.iterator]();

for (const item of firstArray) {
  // Initial code doing stuff with item
  const additionalItem = generatorOverMyAdditionalAray.next();  
  // More code doing stuff with item and additionalItem
  console.log(item, additionalItem.value);
}
```